# Tracking Google Cloud CDN cache hit rate

Tags: caching, google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-cdn

I have a Google Cloud CDN set up for a Google Cloud Storage bucket, and everything seems to be working correctly.  When I check "Network services > Cloud CDN in the GCP console, I see my load balancer with the correct backend and a "Cache hit ratio".  The cache hit ratio moves about quite a lot and ranges between 0 and 90%.  While I understand that this will vary, I would still like to track the hit ratio.

Using Stackdriver, I can monitor the load balancer, but I can't see any metric for "hit ratio" when looking into the load balancer.

Is there a way to see a time series metric for "cache hit ratio" for a specific load balancer using Stackdriver (or any other method)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this document](https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/logging#what_is_logged) Cache Hit get logged using the field "httpRequest.cacheHit=true". You can create a [Log-based Metric](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/logs-based-metrics/#too-many-time-series) to use the logs in [Stackdriver Monitoring](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/docs/)

I didn't find any option to display percentage of cache hit true to show in Stackdriver Monitoring. I am sharing [this document](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/charts/metrics-selector#aggregation-options) which lets you combine time series based on common statistics like max, mean, std.dev etc.

Comment: This works quite well, so I'm marking it as correct.  Do you by any chance know if it's possible to display this as a ration of cache hit = true to total requests?  Right now I simply display cache hit true and cache hit false information, but I can't seem to get the % of cache hit true to show.